# Putting two columns into one

Tags: python

I have a data file with two columns and I wanna put the into a singe column.

Since now I have splitted the columns
with open("test.txt") as input_data:

```
for line in input_data:  # This keeps reading the file
    li=line.strip()
    #print repr(line) #Each line is being returned as a string
    column = line.split()
    # print column
    nb1=column[0]
    nb2=column[1]
```

How can I continue?

Comment: Do you want one column on top of the other column?  Do you want them weaved together where the second element on each line is directly below the first element?

Comment: i have two columns and I want after the last number of the first column the second column to be added. So I need all the numbers to be in a singe column. For example if i have two columns with ten numbers each, I need a column with twenty numbers as output

Comment: Please post a clear example of input and expected output in your answer.

Comment: i have "1 10" and i want to put 10 under 1. (Sorry but I really can't find out how to use Markdown formatting in order to explain better)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Python's slicing notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation) combined with the `+` operator on your columns. For example, joining the first two elements of a list is done by:

```
=>>> l=["a","b","c","d"]
>>> a=[l[0]+l[1]]+l[2:]
>>> a
['ab', 'c', 'd']
```

`a=[l[0]+l[1]]+l[2:]` joins (`+`) the first two elements (`[l[0]+l[1]]`) with the remaining columns (`l[2:]`).

In your code, it would probably be:

```
columns = [column[0]+ column[1]]+ column[2:]
```

Comment: actually what i need (sorry for not making it clear) is to put b under a (in your example) so to make a column with two elements a,b

Answer (score 0):

I changed nb1 and nb2 into lists and appended the column values to each adding '\n' so they are written on a new line.  The output file has a single column with the values from column 1 on top of the values from column 2.  This approach works well for the most part but if you are dealing with really large files this method uses a lot of memory.  If that is an issue you can form your output file in two passes writing first the first column to file and then the second column.

```
nb1 = []
nb2 = []
with open('input.txt','r') as input_data:
  for line in input_data:
    column = line.strip().split()
    nb1.append(column[0]+'\n')
    if len(column) == 2:
      nb2.append(column[1]+'\n')
with open('output.txt','w') as f:
  f.writelines(nb1)
  f.writelines(nb2)
```

If you wanted the second element in each row under the first element you could use this simpler more memory friendly syntax.

```
with open('input.txt','r') as input_data:
  with open('output.txt','w') as f:
    for line in input_data:
      column = line.strip().split()
      f.write(column[0]+'\n')
      f.write(column[1]+'\n')
```

Comment: thanks a lot for you answer. But what if in column a I have e.g 10 numbers and I want to add after those 10 numbers the numbers of column b (e.g 5 numbers) in order to have a single column c with 15 numbers???

Comment: I updated my answer to cover this.  Just check the size of column and if it has two elements then append the second element to nb2.